# Multiple select queries on the same table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with all my data. I have tried joins, subqueries and unions, but none give me the desired result. I am running Oracle 12g.

This is a sample table:

```
FILENAME | VALUE | RAW
AA       | XX    | ZZ
AA       | YY    | WW
DD       | GG    | II
DD       | HH    | JJ
```

The current SQL statement that I use is:

```
SELECT FILENAME, VALUE VALUE1 FROM TABLE WHERE FILENAME='AA';
SELECT FILENAME, VALUE VALUE2 FROM TABLE WHERE FILENAME='DD';
```

And I get the following result:

```
FILENAME | VALUE1
AA       | XX
AA       | YY
```

and

```
FILENAME | VALUE2
DD       | GG
DD       | HH
```

but I need the result to be:

```
FILENAME | VALUE1 | VALUE2
AA       | XX     | GG
AA       | YY     | HH
```

It doesn't matter if AA or DD is in the FILENAME. There are no foreign keys or unique values that I can do a simple INNER JOIN. I am not able to add new columns to the table. I was hoping to do sort my data and then use Oracle's ROWNUM as a temp column which I could then use to do a SELF JOIN but Oracle won't let me.

Example:

```
SELECT L.FILENAME, L.VALUE VALUE1, R.VALUE VALUE2
FROM TABLE L JOIN TABLE R
ON (L.ROWNUM=R.ROWNUM)
WHERE L.FILENAME IN ('AA','DD');
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In the Subquery you can generate the `row_number`, and then use it to `join` it outside the subquery. Row_number is a pseudo column and you cannot use it directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way using `row_number()` could be as follow.

```
with cte as(
select t.*, row_number() over(partition by FILENAME1 order by value1) as rn
from table1 t
  )
select t1.FILENAME1, t1.value1 as value1, t2.value1 as value2 
from cte t1
join cte t2
on t1.rn = t2.rn and t1.FILENAME1 = 'AA' and t2.FILENAME1 = 'DD'
```

What the above does is that in `cte` it assigned `row_number()` starting from `1` partition by `FILENAME1` and then in main query, it joins the table to itself on `row_number()` and other respective hardcoded values.

**Result:**

```
+-----------+--------+--------+
| FILENAME1 | VALUE1 | VALUE2 |
+-----------+--------+--------+
| AA        | XX     | GG     |
| AA        | YY     | HH     |
+-----------+--------+--------+
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/94c131/7)**

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this way:

```
SELECT T1.FILENAME, T1.VALUE VALUE1, T2.VALUE VALUE2
FROM
(SELECT FILENAME, VALUE, RAW, rownum RNUM FROM TABLE1 WHERE FILENAME = 'AA') T1, 
(SELECT FILENAME, VALUE, RAW, rownum RNUM FROM TABLE1 WHERE FILENAME = 'DD') T2
WHERE T1.RNUM = T2.RNUM;
```

Comment: It should be `rownum`, you can use row_number() as a window function

Comment: Thanks @TomJMuthirenthi, I made the edit. This one doesn't require using window function, so `rownum` should suffice.

Comment: I don't think you need 3 subqueries, you can use `rownum` in the first subquery itself. That should work.

Comment: Yeah, I just confirmed that `rownum` applies to output rows. Thanks.

Comment: @Vashi, thanks, also tried your solution and works flawlessly. Love the simplicity and how easy it reads

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
select a1, a2, b2
  from ( select row_number() over(order by filename) rn_a, filename a1, value a2 from mytable where filename = 'AA' ) inner join
       ( select row_number() over(order by filename) rn_b, value b2 from mytable filename = 'DD' ) on rn_a = rn_b
 order by a2;
```

> where `ROW_NUMBER` is an analytic function, introduced in ver.`8iR2`. It assigns a unique number
>   to each row to which it is applied (either each row in the partition
>   or each row returned by the query). By nesting a subquery using
>   `ROW_NUMBER` inside a query that retrieves the `ROW_NUMBER` values for a
>   specified range, you can find a precise subset of rows from the
>   results of the inner query.

Comment: Whilst code only answers may solve the original problem, some explanation helps in understanding the solution and for future reference,

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan thanks for row_number() function note. Teaches me to look more closely to the docs next time :)